# TotalPurchasers metric in Google Analytics 4 giving wrong results

Tags: python, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We have custom dimension define in Google Analytics Data API v1Beta for extracting data from Google Analytics GA4 account. I am trying to fetch purchaseRevenue and totalPurchasers metric with respect to date, sessionSource,  Sessionmedium, campaignName, pagePath and eventName using python. I want to know what is the Purchasers for different eventName in different campaignName. I am getting correct purchaseRevenue but more
Purchasers when i try to validate totalPurchasers data in ga4. Here is the code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import DateRange
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import Dimension
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import Metric
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import RunReportRequest

client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
## Format Report - run_report method
def format_report(request):
    response = client.run_report(request)
    # Row index
    row_index_names = [header.name for header in response.dimension_headers]
    row_header = []
    for i in range(len(row_index_names)):
        row_header.append([row.dimension_values[i].value for row in response.rows])
    row_index_named = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(np.array(row_header), names = np.array(row_index_names))
    # Row flat data
    metric_names = [header.name for header in response.metric_headers]
    data_values = []
    for i in range(len(metric_names)):
        data_values.append([row.metric_values[i].value for row in response.rows])
    output = pd.DataFrame(data = np.transpose(np.array(data_values, dtype = 'f')), 
                          index = row_index_named, columns = metric_names)
    return output
request = RunReportRequest(
        property='properties/'+property_id,
        dimensions=[            
                Dimension(name="date"),
                Dimension(name="sessionSource"),
                Dimension(name="medium"),
                Dimension(name="campaignName"),
                Dimension(name="pagePath"),
                Dimension(name="eventName"),
                ],
        metrics=[         
                Metric(name="purchaseRevenue"),
                Metric(name="totalPurchasers")
            ],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-02-01", end_date="2023-02-07")],
    )
```

Here is the data it is showing me through api

````py
df.totalPurchasers.sum() ```
213.0
```python
 df.purchaseRevenue.sum() ```
13710.0

but in ga4 it is showing 191 purchasers but revenue is correct.
[GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMBFY.png)
````

Comment: Seems like issue in API

Answer (score 0):

You are using right metrics.

Try increasing the limit of rows, by default it is 10K. I think after increasing rows, you will get complete data and then values will be matched.

Comment: Update: Changed some dimension, used sessionCampaignName & sessionMedium instead of campaignName & medium and increased the limit from 10k to 100k. Now it is showing me right purchasers.